# python indenting failure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was trying to write a class for a little program i've been working on, and i ran into an odd failure of indenting. I was wondering if there's genuinely something wrong with what i wrote, or if it's the parser's fault. This fails in Fedora 15's python 3.2 package.

```
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if CharacterStats.usesSubStats:
      if key in self.subStats:
        return self.subStats[key]
    elif key in self.stats: #change this to 'if' and it works
      return self.stats[key]
    else:
      raise KeyError(key)
    #otherwise we end up right here.
```

As requested so you can run it: http://pastebin.com/d8yQUm3U

Comment: Fyi, the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to use 4-space indentation - that makes your code more readable.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you've told it to. It's certainly not the parser's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to throw a KeyError if
usesSubStats is True and key is not in subStats or if usesSubStats is
False and key is not in stats.  So I think the problem is that
if/elif/else chaining doesn't work like you think it does.

Consider:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'first'
    elif x == 2:
        return 'second'
    else:
        return 'other'
```

produces

```
>>> f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)
('first', 'second', 'other', 'other')
```

which I hope does what's expected and is the pattern you should keep in mind.  Since in your test code useSubStats is True, only the first branch is ever tested:

```
def condition(lab, val):
    print('testing condition', lab);
    return val

def g():
    if condition(1, True):
        return 'first branch'
    elif condition(2, False):
        return 'second branch'
    else:
        return 'other branch'
    return 'fallthrough'


>>> g()
testing condition 1
'first branch'
```

So your code is behaving like this:

```
def h():
    if condition(1, True):
        if condition('1b', False):
            return 'first branch'
    elif condition(2, False):
        return 'second branch'
    else:
        return 'other branch'
    return 'fallthrough'

>>> h()
testing condition 1
testing condition 1b
'fallthrough'
```

I'm not exactly sure how you think it should be behaving, but it seems like you expect that after the "if key in self.subStats" test fails, execution should move back to the next member of the if/elif/else branch one level up and test that.  That's simply not how it works, though.

There are several easy ways to get the behaviour you want: one is to flatten it so that it's

```
    if CharacterStats.usesSubStats and key in self.subStats:
```

instead, which will evaluate to False and so the next branch *will* be tested, or --as you discovered yourself -- make the elif an if, which again leads to that condition being independently tested, or rewrite as in an earlier answer.

Does that make sense?  The if/elif/else list describes a series of possibilities, with conditions tested sequentially, *and only the branch corresponding to the first true condition (taking the final else as 'elif 1:') is executed*.  You don't move to the next branch depending on what happens *within* a branch.

Comment: Yeah, i was for some reason thinking that if it went into the first branch, and the `if` within there failed, it would jump back out to the elif; and not jump out altogether. The sad result of coding in the middle of the night with a bit of a hangover.

Answer (score 2):

You can end up on the line marked `otherwise we end up right here` if and only if `CharacterStats.usesSubStats` is true and `key in self.subStats` is false.

When you change the `elif` to `if`, you eliminate this possibility: the code can never reach the `otherwise we end up right here` line.

It's hard to say which of the two versions is correct. Provided I've guessed your intentions correctly, perhaps the following would be a clearer alternative to both of them:

```
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if CharacterStats.usesSubStats:
        if key in self.subStats:
            return self.subStats[key]
    elif key in self.stats:
        return self.stats[key]
    raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: in the implementation as in the original question, the only time anything is returned (or thrown) is if the key is in self.subStats otherwise nothing is returned. if i take the else statement out, it gives a KeyError for any key that isn't in self.subStats. The only way i found to make this work properly is if you just replace the elif with if.

Comment: @Till: Could you reduce your code to small complete example that we can run, and provide the inputs on which it behaves contrary to your expectations?

Comment: That's not really a minimal example. Can you boil it down to just your __getitem__ method and a few examples of calls to that method that test for the result? Try writing it as a (failing) unittest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should indent the `#otherwise..` with the `raise`, as the latter is inside a final `else` and the "outer block" will never be reached.. Hence a reasonable, IMO, IndentationError.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

Since `self.stats` and `self.subStats` are dictionaries, they will both raise a `KeyError` anyway if they don't contain `key`.

So why not just write:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if CharacterStats.usesSubStats:
        return self.subStats[key]
    return self.stats[key]
```

Or perhaps:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        if CharacterStats.usesSubStats:
            return self.subStats[key]
        return self.stats[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise CharacterStatsError(key)
```

Comment: This won't work, because your snippet would assume that the key is always in `self.subStats` so long as `CharacterStats.usesSubStats` is true. This isn't the case though. But i am starting to see how silly i've laid out my class.